# Sharing a TueCrypted external hard drive over a windows LAN

Tags: windows, network-share, truecrypt

As the title says. The drive is encrypted with truecrypt so every time it gets mounted I have to explicitly share it from the host machine. This is inconvenient because windows has to scan the contents of the drive each time. Is there any way to make the entire host machine shared without having to scan/rescan files?

Answer (score 1):

From the [TrueCrypt docs](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=sharing-over-network), it seems that you'll need to make it a system favorite volume :

> Remarks: Note that, when you restart
>   the system, the network share will be
>   automatically restored only if the
>   volume is a system favorite volume or
>   an encrypted system partition/drive
>   (for more information on how to
>   configure a volume as a system
>   favorite volume, see the chapter
>   [System Favorite Volumes](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=system-favorites)).

Comment: very close. however, this solution requires that the system partition be encrypted too, which it isn't.

Comment: From my reading, that's not correct. The volume needs to be *either* a system volume, or a "system favorite volume" which is something you can define in the TrueCrypt software. It's possible that I missed something in my reading, but I'm pretty certain that's what it says there.

Answer (score 0):

I have a batch file to do this on our Windows 2003 server when it gets rebooted. This does not scan the contents of the drive.

```
rem mount TC volume as N:
"c:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe" /v c:\data.tc /ln /q

rem create network share
net share MyData=N:\my_data /cache:None

rem set share permissions - google for rmtshare.exe
rmtshare \\%COMPUTERNAME%\MyData /grant everyone:Read
```